# Awful beeping sound on boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, macbook, bootloader

I formated the entire hard drive and installed Ubuntu 14.04 in a Macbook 5.2.

Ubuntu boots decently fast, however there is a disconcerning garbled image on screen:

[image]

After that Ubuntu runs fairly well but once I restart the machine a long beeping sound takes place instead of booting, the laptop remains with power but nothing will happen after that.

I have to manually shut down the laptop and restart, Ubuntu will load but the next restart will include the same beeping sound of death.

I already flushed the PRAM with hotkeys and by removed the Battery several times.

Nothing has fixed this problem, and Im unable to install Mac OS X to troubleshoot it.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a VGA adapter, install Mavericks and manually flash the EFI firmware [following this thread](http://pubmem.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/flash-efi-firmware-update-manually-on-a-macbook-51/). The steps are intended for Macbook 5,1 but the workaround is identical for 5,2. Fortunately the beeping sound is gone after flashing the firmware.

Ubuntu 11.04 was responsible for this since it replaced the EFI loader with it's own version. The beep came from both speakers, a monotone sound with no variations and takes about 4 seconds.